# Can you get around having to run 'import' when you load a script with ScriptLoader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

Due to the environment I have to implement my code into, I can't use 'import'. I'm able to get the library I need just fine but I'm running into the following error when trying to use it.

"jQuery.Deferred exception: videojs is not defined ReferenceError: videojs is not defined"

I've found workarounds for videoJS that require using something like the following

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
window.videojs = videojs;
require('videojs-http-source-selector');
```

Unfortunately that won't work since import is out of the question. Is there a way to work around this?

Below is my code in question. I use the ScriptLoader to load the library by file path in my solution.

```
/*This JS is meant to create an HMTL video component, then stream JSVideo/HLS to it. It's integrated in a no-code/low-code solution and is very particular about structure.*/

 function MyControl() { };

 MyControl.prototype.initialize = function(host, component){
  
/*Here we load our libraries. We must load it this way because of the way we integrate javascript into the no code solution*/
   $.when(
     $DP.ScriptLoader.LoadScript(
       virtualPath + "/scripts/FormControls/jsFiles/video.js"
     )
    ) 

   

  // Here we assign 'host' to a variable on this control,
    //   so that we can access it later:
  this.host = host;
  
  

  // Create and configure the video elemnt:
  
  var video = document.createElement('video-js');
  video.setAttribute("id","videoplayer");
  video.setAttribute("class","video-js vjs-default-skin");
  

  
 
  // Add the video to the 'host' jquery object:
  host.append(video);
  //Gets the source and plays on our video element previosuly made.
  const player = videojs('videoplayer', {
            html5: {
                hls: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            },
            controls : true,
            fluid: true,
            controlBar: {
                children: ['playToggle', 'volumePanel', 'currentTimeDisplay', 'timeDivider', 'durationDisplay', 'progressControl', 'liveDisplay', 'seekToLive', 'remainingTimeDisplay', 'customControlSpacer', 'playbackRateMenuButton', 'chaptersButton', 'descriptionsButton', 'subsCapsButton', 'audioTrackButton', 'settingMenuButton', 'qualitySelector','fullscreenToggle']
            },
            preload : 'auto',
            poster : '',
        });
    player.src({
      src: 'http://demo.unified-streaming.com/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8',
      type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });
     player.play(); 
  };
 

 MyControl.prototype.resize = function(height, width) {
  if (this.host && height && width && (height > 0) && (width > 0)) {
   this.host.css({ width: width, height: height });
  }
 };

 MyControl.prototype.setValue = function(data){
  // This control has no inputs, so no code is necessary here.
 };

 MyControl.prototype.getValue = function() {
  // Output data should be an object with properties that match the
    
  return {
  };
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
var videojs = require(/path/+'video.js');
```

Comment: Trying this returned 'require is not defined'. Did I write this correctly? Thanks for the help!

Comment: var videojs = require(virtualPath + "/scripts/FormControls/jsFiles/video.js" +'video.js');